# How to convert the following optimization problem to SDP format?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, regularization, nuclear-norm

I want to convert the optimization problem $x \in \mathbb R^n$ to SDP format to further solve it using the famous solvers like sdpt3 and sedumi.

$$\text{minimize} \quad \| A(x) - B \|_* + \lambda \| D x \|_1$$

where $A$ is a linear mapping, and $B$ and $D$ are matrices.

Comment: Why not use CVXPY?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the thing is that i have a fast routine that handles the nuclear norm problems but only with quadratic regularization , so if i somehow deal with the second term i may be able to use that routine

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the routine supports only linear matrix inequality constraint , that constraint term is not allowed

Comment: Redha, I'm afraid you're contradicting yourself. If you want to use SDPT3 or SeDuMi, you convert things to SDP format and you forget about your "fast routine", because that's not relevant. If you have a fast routine you want to use, you have to build your own custom algorithm around it. You need to decide which path you want to take.

Comment: The challenge you're facing is that the $D$ matrix effectively makes it impossible for you to use a garden-variety proximal gradient algorithm. That's one reason we built TFOCS

Comment: @MichaelGrant what is the most efficient solver for this problem and in what form the problem is solved , so far mosek is the fastest but goes slow when increasing data size

Comment: You are likely doing the best you can unless you implement your own

Comment: You might consider using iteratively reweighted least squares (IRLS) with your fast routine for the quadratically regularized problem handling the least squares subproblems.